# Magento 1.9 Image Dataflow problem

Tags: magento-1.9

We recently stopped using magmi and we have gone back to the magento dataflow profiles to upload product data. One problem we are having though is with images.

This is what our upload CSV looks like:

```
sku,image,small_image,thumbnail
MCS-000000,/000000k.jpg,/000000k.jpg,/000000k.jpg
MCS-100000,/100000k.jpg,/100000k.jpg,/100000k.jpg
MCS-200001,/200001k.jpg,/200001k.jpg,/200001k.jpg
MCS-200002,/200002k.jpg,/200002k.jpg,/200002k.jpg
MCS-200101,/200101k.jpg,/200101k.jpg,/200101k.jpg
MCS-200102,/200102k.jpg,/200102k.jpg,/200102k.jpg
MCS-200103,/200103k.jpg,/200103k.jpg,/200103k.jpg
```

It's pretty standard stuff, and matches all examples I have seen.

The problem we are getting is this, the images are assigned to the product without a problem, but magento is not setting the images as default images. See here on the admin panel for a product.

[image: product image screenshot]
To make the image appear where it should we have to manually click each checkbox and save the product.

I have tried indexing, clearing cache... all that sort of stuff.

I really am lost, what error am I making here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Images have to be set on store view basis.

Try to add the "store" column to you csv files